# Getting data from a .txt file in C

Tags: c, file, memory

I'm new to C and I have to read data from a file, and I need to store that data in an array. I'm using `FILE *fptr; fptr = fopen(¨filename.txt¨, ¨r¨)` to read and `fscanf(fptr,"%d", &num);` to get the file data, however when compiling I only seem to get the memory location for it *(I think? the file I'm using to try the code out has the number 5368 and I'm getting 6422296)*

> int main(void)

> ```
>     {
>     FILE *fptr;
>     fptr = fopen("example.txt" , "r");
>     if ((fptr = fopen("example.txt","r")) == NULL)
>     {
>       printf("Error! opening file");
>       exit(1);
>     }
>     int num;
>     fscanf(fptr,"%d", &num);
>     printf("VALUE OF NUM IS %d", &num);
>
>     fclose(fptr);
>     return 0;
>     }
> ```

Comment: Please post a [mcve], the expected and actual output.

Comment: "*I'm getting 6422296*". How and where are you seeing that? Show the code that prints/examines/tests that value. That is, please provide a complete [mre].

Comment: This doesn't compile as you use something besides double quotes for char * arguments.

Comment: `printf("VALUE OF NUM IS %d", num);` - ie take out the `&`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a minimal example demonstrating reading a couple of numbers from filename.txt into an array `num`.  You need to add error handling, and if you cannot fix the size (`LEN`) then either calculate it by figuring out how numbers is in the file, or `realloc` the size of the `num` array as needed:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LEN 2

int main() {
    FILE *fptr = fopen("./filename.txt", "r");
    int num[LEN];
    for(int i = 0; i < LEN; i++) {
        fscanf(fptr, "%d", num + i);
        printf("%d\n", num[i]);
    }
    fclose(fptr);
}
```